# How to parse this date in java?

Tags: java, date, datetime, simpledateformat

how to parse this date format in java?
2022-01-19T18:14:17+03:00
I tried SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssz"), but it didn't work.

Comment: You don't have the `T` in your pattern...

Comment: Well, you've got nothing to parse the `T` in your pattern, for starters. Change the space to `'T'`.

Comment: I'd avoid `SimpleDateFormat` where possible, it's a legacy piece of jdk.  Take a look at the newer java 8 time package: https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro

Comment: If you're going to use java 8 time (which you should), this is just a standard ISO8601 time. You can parse it with `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZonedDateTime t = ZonedDateTime.parse("2022-01-19T18:14:17+03:00");
```

This uses the default zone you are in (only the offset +03:00 is given. `toString` is the inverse operation.

The format shown is that of an `OffsetDateTime`, which needs some time zone, a (default) time zone ID, to have a full ZonedDateTime. Note that an OffsetDateTime is *incomplete* without the time zone. It migh be used to indicate a latitude on earth, but the local clocks might provide several differing times. Normally choose a ZonedDateTime.

The format of the input is the ISO standard with `T` for *time*.

This means you do not need a `DateTimeFormatter`.

If you need to use the obsolete old `Date`:

```
Date date = Date.fromInstant(t.toInstant());
```

Comment: Did you mean [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) rather than `ZonedDateTime`?

Comment: @BasilBourque OffsetDateTime is an incomplete artifice not tied to a real calendar / time, say with summer time. So either use UTC or ZonedDateTime (wrt. your own Locale). What do you think? (I think the zone was dropped.)

Comment: I agree with you in general, yes. But when specifically parsing an input string which indicates only an offset without a time zone, then you should be showing the use of `OffsetDateTime`. You could additionally show converting that `OffsetDateTime` to a `ZonedDateTime` by specifying a zone. But parsing an offset string as a `ZonedDateTime` is misleading and confusing.

Comment: @BasilBourque your comment is indeed valuable, but an `OffsetDateTime` looks to me like a built-in time bomb. Using `OffsetDateTime` looks so much more apt. I'll add non-code text however.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it doesn't read 'T' "2022-01-19T18:14:17+03:00", or try to fit the data to [Examples](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) formats

Comment: The format asked in the question has been changed. The owner of the question asked how to solve the specified format. It's not a valid solution.